# Would USBs on non-Apple monitor with DisplayPort work?

Tags: usb, macbook, displayport, thunderbolt

Would the USB ports on a 3rd party monitor work on MacBook Pro with Thunderbolt?

I have a MacBook Pro 13" from ~2012 (13", no retina, i7 model) that I'm still pretty happy with. Now I'm sick of disconnecting all the peripherals every day when going out with my laptop, so I'm wondering if there are monitors with `DisplayPort` that can also plug 2-3 USBs and eventually ethernet cable (but not at all required). But the Apple Thunderbolt costs ~1000 EUR where I live. My reasoning is that for 1/2 price I can get a 4k monitor or for even less I can get a 1440p monitor that has USBs.

Comment: Why not get a USB3 Docking station? Something like [Targus USB3 Docking Station](http://targus.com/au/product_details.asp?sku=ACP71AU) it only needs 1 USB3 connection to your Macbook, and it will provide ethernet, and display, and several USB ports.

Comment: Well, first it's yet another $100 device I have to buy and use. Then it says it supports up to Mac OS X Lion (no Mavericks or Yosemite). And it says it supports monitors up to 2048 x 1152. Why would I need one, if DisplayPort already supports USBs on MBP? I can live with wireless connection (No Ethernet)...

Comment: If you provide some monitor that you had in mind maybe other users can comment whether it works or not. My current guess is that thunderbolt protocol allows for data (for USB hub) and display but if the monitor only accept Display only, then USB hub may still need it's own USB cable rather than getting the data feed via the DP cable.

Comment: Pre-Thunderbolt, but I have a couple of Dells that have built-in USB2 hubs, but they do need specific USB2 cables from the Mac to use them; can't be done over display port etc itself.